# Overriding Plugin Function in Child Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, child-theme

I have a plugin and a custom post type class like this.

I want to override one its function in my child theme.

```
class Inspiry_Property_Post_Type {

/**
 * Register Property Post Type
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function register_property_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Properties', 'Post Type General Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Property', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Properties', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Property:', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Properties', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'New Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => apply_filters( 'inspiry_property_slug', __( 'property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ) ),
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Real Estate Property', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'comments' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-building',
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'property', $args );

}

/**
 * Register Property Type Taxonomy
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function register_property_type_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Property Type', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Property Type', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Types', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Property Types', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Property Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Property Type:', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Property Type Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Property Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Property Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Property Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Property Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Property Types with commas', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Property Types', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Property Types', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Property Types', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => apply_filters( 'inspiry_property_type_slug', __( 'property-type', 'inspiry-real-estate' ) ),
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'property-type', array( 'property' ), $args );

}

/**
 * Register Property Status Taxonomy
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function register_property_status_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Property Status', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Property Status', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Statuses', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Property Statuses', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Property Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Property Status:', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Property Status Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Property Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Property Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Property Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Property Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Property Statuses with commas', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Property Statuses', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Property Statuses', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Property Statuses', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => apply_filters( 'inspiry_property_status_slug', __( 'property-status', 'inspiry-real-estate' ) ),
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'property-status', array( 'property' ), $args );

}

/**
 * Register Property City Taxonomy
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function register_property_city_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Property City', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Property City', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Locations', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Property Cities', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Property City', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Property City:', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Property City Name', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Property City', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Property City', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Property City', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Property City', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Property Cities with commas', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Property Cities', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Property Cities', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Property Cities', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => apply_filters( 'inspiry_property_city_slug', __( 'property-city', 'inspiry-real-estate' ) ),
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'property-city', array( 'property' ), $args );

}

/**
 * Register custom columns
 *
 * @param   array   $defaults
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @return  array   $defaults
 */
public function register_custom_column_titles ( $defaults ) {

    $new_columns = array(
        "thumb"     => __( 'Photo', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        "id"        => __( 'Custom ID', 'inspiry-real-estate' ),
        "price"     => __( 'Price', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
    );

    $last_columns = array();

    if ( count( $defaults ) > 5 ) {

        unset( $defaults['author'] );

        $last_columns = array_splice( $defaults, 2, 4 );

        // Simplify column titles
        $last_columns[ 'taxonomy-property-type' ]   = __( 'Type', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
        $last_columns[ 'taxonomy-property-status' ] = __( 'Status', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
        $last_columns[ 'taxonomy-property-city' ]   = __( 'Location', 'inspiry-real-estate' );

    }

    $defaults = array_merge( $defaults, $new_columns );
    $defaults = array_merge( $defaults, $last_columns );

    return $defaults;
}

/**
 * Display custom column for properties
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string $column_name
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @return  void
 */
public function display_custom_column ( $column_name ) {
    global $post;

    switch ( $column_name ) {

        case 'thumb':
            if ( has_post_thumbnail ( $post->ID ) ) {
                ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 130, 130 ) );?></a><?php
            } else {
                _e ( 'No Image', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
            }
            break;

        case 'id':
            $property_id = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true );
            if( ! empty ( $property_id ) ) {
                echo $property_id;
            } else {
                _e ( 'NA', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
            }
            break;

        case 'price':
            $property_price = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true );
            if ( !empty ( $property_price ) ) {
                $price_amount = doubleval( $property_price );
                $price_postfix = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix', true );
                echo Inspiry_Property::format_price( $price_amount, $price_postfix );
            } else {
                _e ( 'NA', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Register meta boxes related to property post type
 *
 * @param   array   $meta_boxes
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @return  array   $meta_boxes
 */
public function register_meta_boxes ( $meta_boxes ){

    $prefix = 'REAL_HOMES_';

    // Agents
    $agents_array = array( -1 => __( 'None', 'inspiry-real-estate' ) );
    $agents_posts = get_posts( array (
        'post_type' => 'agent',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'suppress_filters' => 0,
        ) );
    if ( ! empty ( $agents_posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $agents_posts as $agent_post ) {
            $agents_array[ $agent_post->ID ] = $agent_post->post_title;
        }
    }

    // Property Details Meta Box
    $default_desc = __( 'Consult theme documentation for required image size.', 'inspiry-real-estate' );
    $gallery_images_desc = apply_filters( 'inspiry_gallery_description', $default_desc );
    $video_image_desc = apply_filters( 'inspiry_video_description', $default_desc );
    $slider_image_desc = apply_filters( 'inspiry_slider_description', $default_desc );

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'property-meta-box',
        'title' => __('Property', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
        'pages' => array('property'),
        'tabs' => array(
            'details' => array(
                'label' => __('Basic Information', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-admin-home',
            ),
            'gallery' => array(
                'label' => __('Gallery Images', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
            ),
            'video' => array(
                'label' => __('Property Video', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-format-video',
            ),
            'agent' => array(
                'label' => __('Agent Information', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-businessman',
            ),
            'misc' => array(
                'label' => __('Misc', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
            ),
            'home-slider' => array(
                'label' => __('Homepage Slider', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt',
            ),
            'banner' => array(
                'label' => __('Top Banner', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
            ),
        ),
        'tab_style' => 'left',
        'fields' => array(

            // Details
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_price",
                'name' => __('Sale or Rent Price ( Only digits )', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: 435000', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_price_postfix",
                'name' => __('Price Postfix', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: Per Month', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_size",
                'name' => __('Area Size ( Only digits )', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: 2500', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_size_postfix",
                'name' => __('Size Postfix', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: Sq Ft', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_bedrooms",
                'name' => __('Bedrooms', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: 4', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_bathrooms",
                'name' => __('Bathrooms', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: 2', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_garage",
                'name' => __('Garages', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Example Value: 1', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_id",
                'name' => __('Property ID', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('It will help you search a property directly.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 6,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),


            // Map
            array(
                'type' => 'divider',
                'columns' => 12,
                'id' => 'google_map_divider', // Not used, but needed
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_address",
                'name' => __('Property Address', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Leaving it empty will hide the google map on property detail page.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                // 'std' => 'Miami, FL, USA',
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_location",
                'name' => __('Property Location at Google Map*', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Drag the google map marker to point your property location. You can also use the address field above to search for your property.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'map',
                'std' => '25.761680,-80.191790,14',   // 'latitude,longitude[,zoom]' (zoom is optional)
                'style' => 'width: 95%; height: 400px',
                'address_field' => "{$prefix}property_address",
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'details',
            ),

            array(
                'name' => __('Property Gallery Images', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_images",
                'desc' => $gallery_images_desc,
                'type' => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 48,
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'gallery',
            ),


            // Property Video
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}tour_video_url",
                'name' => __('Virtual Tour Video URL', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('Provide virtual tour video URL. YouTube, Vimeo, SWF File and MOV File are supported', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'video',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Virtual Tour Video Image', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}tour_video_image",
                'desc' => $video_image_desc,
                'type' => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 1,
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'video',
            ),

            // Agents
            array(
                'name' => __('What to display in agent information box ?', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}agent_display_option",
                'type' => 'radio',
                'std' => 'none',
                'options' => array(
                    'my_profile_info' => __('Author information.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                    'agent_info' => __('Agent Information. ( Select the agent below )', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                    'none' => __('None. ( Hide information box )', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                ),
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'agent',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Agent', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}agents",
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => $agents_array,
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'agent',
            ),

            // Misc
            array(
                'name' => __('Mark this property as featured ?', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}featured",
                'type' => 'radio',
                'std' => 0,
                'options' => array(
                    1 => __('Yes ', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                    0 => __('No', 'inspiry-real-estate')
                ),
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'misc',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}attachments",
                'name' => __('Attachments', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('You can attach PDF files, Map images OR other documents to provide further details related to property.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'file_advanced',
                'mime_type' => '',
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'misc',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => "{$prefix}property_private_note",
                'name' => __('Private Note', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('In this textarea, You can write your private note about this property. This field will not be displayed anywhere else.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'std' => "",
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'misc',
            ),

            // Homepage Slider
            array(
                'name' => __('Do you want to add this property in Homepage Slider ?', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'desc' => __('If Yes, Then you need to provide a slider image below.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}add_in_slider",
                'type' => 'radio',
                'std' => 'no',
                'options' => array(
                    'yes' => __('Yes ', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                    'no' => __('No', 'inspiry-real-estate')
                ),
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'home-slider',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Slider Image', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}slider_image",
                'desc' => $slider_image_desc,
                'type' => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 1,
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'home-slider',
            ),

            // Top Banner
            array(
                'name' => __('Top Banner Image', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}page_banner_image",
                'desc' => __('Upload the banner image, If you want to change it for this property. Otherwise default banner image uploaded from theme options will be displayed. Image should have minimum width of 2000px and minimum height of 230px.', 'inspiry-real-estate'),
                'type' => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 1,
                'columns' => 12,
                'tab' => 'banner',
            )

        )
    );

    // apply a filter before returning meta boxes
    $meta_boxes = apply_filters( 'property_meta_boxes', $meta_boxes );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

}

How can I override the **register_meta_boxes** function? I want to remove some of the meta boxes defined in this parent class. Thanks!

Comment: What does the question actually has to do with wordpress?

Comment: Because I actually have a wordpress plugin with a custom post type class and I need to override one of its function. I've tried to do it but I've failed so far. So instead of copying the whole code, I've put something much simpler as example.

Comment: Extend the class

Comment: @jdm2112 do I have to create a new object of the child class after that?

Comment: See darrinb's answer below.  Then read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: This is a very generic php question that has nothing to do with wordpress, and in the way you ask it, it is impossible to give any useful answer.

Comment: Why don't you use [`remove meta box`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) instead of trying to override the whole class?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. Thanks for all your replies :)

Comment: Just wondered if you'd tried the remove_meta_box function? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Answer (score 1):

In general you can not override functions or methods in PHP. Code can be written to support such things, but it needs to be planned in advance, and your snippet is not big enough to be able to decide if it is possible or not in your case.

The good thing, is that you do not need to override any function at all as the output of that function is filterable by using the `'property_meta_boxes'` filter, so just do something like

```
add_filter('property_meta_boxes','wpse223273_meta_boxes');

function wpse223273_meta_boxes($metaboxes) {
  $my_meta = array(.... your meta box settings....);
  return $my_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the main class is set up, you can create a child class of the parent class.  Something like:

```
class Custom_Post_Type_Child extends Custom_Post_Type {
{
    public function doSomething ( $var ){
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Comment: do I have to create a new object of the child class after that?

Comment: Again, depending on the parent class, but more than likely, yes.

Comment: This only declares a function with the same name, it doesn't actually override its functionality. this at best is only half an answer

Comment: Ask half a question, get half an answer.

Comment: This answers the whole question, such as it is.  To override the method `doSomething()` you extend the class and define a new version of `doSomething()`.  Just as this question show, and exactly what the OP asked for, albeit poorly.

Comment: @darrinb, the idea is that answers should be useful. If you know it is not, then why answer at all.

Comment: @jdm2112, you can not override functions or methods in php, unless there is some infrastructure for that. Extending a class is pointless if it is not in place